# I have to reload bashrc each time

Tags: 13.04, bashrc

Despite the fact that I added some commands in `.bashrc`, I have to say "`source ~/.bashrc`" each time after rebooting.

**.bashrc**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH=/opt/scala/sbt-0.12.2/bin:$PATH
```

Without saying "`souce ~/.bashrc`" the command `sbt` doesn't work.

```
No command 'sbt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'st' from package 'suckless-tools' (universe)
 Command 'sb' from package 'lrzsz' (universe)
 Command 'mbt' from package 'mbt' (universe)
 Command 'sbd' from package 'cluster-glue' (main)
 Command 'sb2' from package 'scratchbox2' (universe)
 Command 'skt' from package 'latex-sanskrit' (universe)
 Command 'sbmt' from package 'atfs' (universe)
 Command 'lbt' from package 'lbt' (universe)
sbt: command not found
```

Comment: It is in a graphic terminal or in a virtual console, or in ssh? Do you have a `.profile` or `.bash_profile`?

Comment: this is a console app.

Comment: `.bashrc` is for interactive non-login shell, for Ubuntu it works with `~/.profile`. If you have a `~/.bash_profile` (for interactive login shell), the above-mentioned 2 won't be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basics: `.bashrc` is for interactive non-login shell, while `~/.bash_profile` is for interactive login-shell.

For

- Interactive non-login shell, initialization order: System wide bashrc (SYS_BASHRC) default `/etc/bash.bashrc` => `~/.bashrc`
- Interactive login shell, initialization order: `/etc/profile` [^sysconfdir] => `~/.bash_profile` => `~/.bash_login` => `~/.profile`.

Ubuntu by default uses `~/.profile` to load `~/.bashrc`, if `~/.bash_profile` exists, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` will NOT be loaded at shell initialization.

So make sure you don't have a `~/.bash_profile`, put what you want in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`.